# string with quotes in C#

Tags: c#

How I can have a string value like **"PropertyBag["ABCD"]"** ? I want it to assign to a value of a chart in my WPF App. I am using it like as shown below :

```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        foreach (var str in vm.Data)
        {
            string name = "ABCD";
            LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
            lineSeries.ItemsSource = new ViewModel().Data;
            lineSeries.XBindingPath = "Date";
            lineSeries.YBindingPath = "PropertyBag[\" + name + \"]"; // here i am getting error saying - Input string was not in a correct format 
            lineSeries.IsSeriesVisible = true;
            lineSeries.ShowTooltip = true;
            chart.Series.Add(lineSeries);
        }
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

I want it like
lineSeries.YBindingPath = "PropertyBag["ABCD"]" //
(should include all 4 double quotes). How it is possible ??

I tried this also, but still same error :

```
  lineSeries.YBindingPath = String.Format(@"PropertBag[""{0}""]", name);
```

Comment: Google is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-put-quotation-marks-in-a-string-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: You've got escaped quotes inside the square braces, did you also want to put them at the start/end of the string? Those are missing if so.

Comment: What is LinePath, and what does it expect `YBindingPath` to look like? This isn't really a C# issue - it's a matter of "whatever the library you're using can accept".

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes I want all the 4 quotes. Can u pls give me a sample ?

Comment: `lineSeries.YBindingPath = $"PropertyBag[\"{name}\"]";`, However, this almost certainly the wrong way to bind the WPF control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must work and it is a more elegant solution:

```
string name = "ABC";
lineSeries.YBindingPath = string.Format("\"PropertyBag[\"{0}\"]\"", name);
```

You escaped the quote before and after **name**, in doing that you didn't specify where the first part of the string ends and where the second one starts. To avoid errors like that it is better to use the ***Format*** method. It makes code easier to read and maintain.

The following solution:

```
string.Format(@"""PropertyBag[""{0}""]""", name)
```

is good too, but I think the first one is more readable. I personally like more the first one. But it is up to you, just avoid concatenation; in modern programming it is deprecated especially when the language has more efficient and powerful tools to do the job.

**** UPDATE ****

If you use the most recent versions of .NET you can also use an even more elegant solution, through string interpolation (like in Kotlin and Swift):

```
string name = "ABC";
lineSeries.YBindingPath = $"\"PropertyBag[\"{name}\"]\"";
```

Comment: @Sergiob. Your answer is correct.

Comment: The triple quotes only support by C# 11, namely Raw string literals

Answer (score 1):

You're escaping the quotes before the pluses, meaning they get interpreted as characters, not as addition operators. You need to add additional quotation marks, like so:

```
lineSeries.YBindingPath = "\"PropertyBag[\"" + name + "\"]\"";
```

This way, you define two new strings; a prefix and a suffix to the `name` variable.

You can also use string interpolation, which results in cleaner code:

```
lineSeries.YBindingPath = $"\"PropertyBag[\"{name}\"]\"";
```

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' It gives PropertyBag["ABCD"]. But I want it like "PropertyBag["PRSPR"]" - should include all the 4 quotes.

Comment: user interpolation, not concatenation

Comment: @JassimS oops, sorry, didn't notice that you wanted to surround the string with quotes as well! I've updated the answer to include them.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#quoted-string-literals)

```
("PropertyBag[\"" + name + "\"]");
```

[Verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#verbatim-string-literals)

```
(@"PropertyBag[""{0}""]", name);
```

Try Raw string literals if you're on C# 11